# 404 when enqueue_script using plugin_url

Tags: functions, wp-enqueue-script, plugins-url

So i'm adding a script into my site via `functions.php` that lives in the plugins directory. The code is pretty straightforward:

```
function add_jq_script() {
      wp_register_script('r_footer', plugins_url('/responsiveFooter.js', __FILE__), array('jquery'),'1.1', true);
     wp_enqueue_script('r_footer');
 } 

add_action( 'wp_enqueue_scripts', 'add_jq_script', 999 );
```

the plugins seem to be working on local site, but in dev console, i'm getting a 404 that seems to be concatting my site-url and the absolute url for my plugins:
`http://localhost/~thisuser/wordpress/wp-content/plugins/Users/thisuser/Sites/wordpress/wp-content/themes/liberty/responsiveFooter.js?ver=1.1`

i'm a bit new to wordpress, the url should be `http://localhost/~thisuser/wordpress/wp-content/plugins/responsiveFooter.js`

is there some wp-option i need to change or some plugin setting somewhere to fix this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`plugins_url` will output the absolute file path of the plugins directory in your WordPress install.

This of course won't work for a client (browser) calling a script.

To access scripts from the plugins directory, you'll want to use `plugin_dir_url()` which will get you the url of the plugin directory.

**Some things to note about `plugin_dir_url()`**

- You need to specify the directory of the plugin name your script is located
- The function output contains a trailing slash, so you won't need to concatenate a slash.

Lets say your plugin is called "my_plugin" and the script is located in a "js" directory, your script registration would look something like this:

```
wp_register_script('r_footer', plugins_dir_url() . 'my_plugin/js/responsiveFooter.js', array('jquery'),'1.1', true);
```

Note the omission of `__FILE__` which will output the absolute path of the current file (not what you want).

---

If your script is in your active theme, you'll want to use a different function: `get_stylesheet_directory_uri`

**Some things to note about `get_stylesheet_directory_uri`**

- It requires a trailing slash unlike `plugin_dir_url()`
- You will need to specify the directory path in the theme where your script is located.
- This function works especially well if you are working with child themes, but a child theme is not required. If you are working with a child theme, this function will get the path to the style.css file in your child theme rather than the parent theme.
- Note that the function is ur**i** NOT ur**l**

So lets say your theme is called "my_theme" and the javascript is located in a "js" file, your registration script would look something like this:

```
wp_register_script('r_footer', get_stylesheet_directory_uri() . '/my_theme/js/responsiveFooter.js', array('jquery'),'1.1', true);
```

---

**Links to documentation:**

- plugin_dir_url - https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/plugin_dir_url
- get_stylesheet_uri - https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/get_stylesheet_directory_uri
- get_template_directory_uri (which is an alternative function to get_stylesheet_uri, but isn't advised for child themes) - https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/get_template_directory_uri/
- plugins_url - https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/plugins_url

Comment: thanks! also, i didn't need the `my_theme` part of the `wp_register_script` function for the script in my active directory.

Comment: Glad to hear it did the trick!

Answer (score 0):

You have used wrong callable function in `add_action()`. Your code should be something like this-

```
function add_jq_script() {
      wp_register_script('r_footer', plugins_url('/responsiveFooter.js', __FILE__), array('jquery'),'1.1', true);
     wp_enqueue_script('r_footer');
 } 

add_action( 'wp_enqueue_scripts', 'add_jq_script', 999 );
```

Additionally, according to your code, you need to keep `responsiveFooter.js` and `functions.php` files in the same directory.

**UPDATE:**

Use this code instead. Paste in your `functions.php`-

```
function add_jq_script() {
    wp_register_script('r_footer', plugins_url( '/responsiveFooter.js' ), array( 'jquery' ), '1.1', true );
    wp_enqueue_script('r_footer');
 } 

add_action( 'wp_enqueue_scripts', 'add_jq_script', 999 );
```

Comment: sorry, that was a copy/paste error. my corrected script, and the one you posted are the ones that are giving me the error. i'm thinking now that it is a theme issue? should i be using a child theme for this?

Comment: where did you keep `functions.php` and `responsiveFooter.js` files?

Comment: `responsiveFooter.js` is in `/wordpress/wp-content/plugins/` and `functions.php` is in `wordpress/wp-content/themes/liberty`. Its the functions file that came with the theme

Comment: i have updated the answer. please check.
Note: even if it works, it's not a good idea to keep a JS file directly in the plugins directory.